# Laravel: how to cache route for 5 minutes?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, caching, laravel-artisan

I want to cache one route in Laravel project and clear it for every 5 minutes.

I searched a bunch of articles but only found `artisan route:cache` command and I have no idea if it possible to configure caching time.

So, this is my routes `routes/web.php`:

```
$router->group(['middleware' => ['api','cors']], function () use ($router) {
    $router->get('game', ['uses' => 'GameController@checkGameStatus']);
    $router->get('promo', ['uses' => 'PromoController@sendPromoCode']);
    $router->get('get_leaders', ['uses' => 'GameController@getLeaders']); // <-- cache this for 5m
});
```

And every time when user loads rating page the `getLeaders()` function initiates DB request to get and calculate all user results. Therefore I want to reduce DB load and make it calculating all results once in 5 minutes. The rest of the time `get_leaders` route should send back just cached json output.

How to set such configuration? Is it possible to do just with Laravel (artisan) or should I change `.htaccess` file (I am using apache)?

Comment: Route caching isn't what you're looking for here, route caching just caches the translation of incoming request to controller action not the actual data or response from the controller. To achieve this kind of caching use the normal caching facade inside your controller action https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache#storing-items-in-the-cache

Comment: You probably don't want route caching but object/result caching https://laravel.com/docs/master/cache

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a pretty simple to solve problem actually. In your function `getLeaders()`, you'll need to modify the code:

```
public function getLeaders(){
  $leadersCache = Cache::get("leaders", null);
  if($leadersCache){
    return response()->json(["leaders", $leadersCache], 200);
  }

  $leaders = Leader::where(...)->get();
  Cache::put("leaders", $leaders, 5);

  return response(["leaders", $leaders], 200);
}
```

So, what this does, is first, check if `"leaders"` exists in the cache. If it does, it will simply return that. If it doesn't (which will be the case when this route is first called), then it will do the calculations, and using `Cache::put()`, store it in the cache, then return. For the next 5 minutes, anytime this route is hit, it will return the cached result, until the process is started over again.

Note the above is pseudo-code, as your Controller wasn't shown, but the approach can be easily adapted to existing code. Also, you may need to include `use Cache;` at the top of your Controller, or reference `Cache` via `\Cache::{method}`

Everything about the cache can be found in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache

Comment: Gonna modify this a little because you can use the cache::remember function to simply this a lot

Comment: @AlecJoy Appreciate the edit suggestion, but it's a pretty big deviation from the code I wrote. You are more than welcome to write it as your own answer (I didn't know the `remember` method exists, but definitely seems like a good approach)

Comment: Sounds fair, I'll do that instead

Comment: Thank you! Laravel is so great :)

Answer (score 6):

To add to @TimLewis 's answer, if you're using laravel 5.8 or newer then the Cache::remember function can simplify the controller code quite a bit

```php
public function getLeaders(){
  $leaders = Cache::remember('leaders', 300, function () {
    return Leader::where(...)->get();
  });
  return response()->json(['leaders' => $leaders]);
}
```

The `Cache::remember` function takes care of the entire caching workflow, it first checks the cache for the leaders object and returns that if it exists. If not, it runs the code inside the closure and stores the result in the cache under the key specified in the first param, for the number of seconds specified in the second param. So in this case it would cache the result under the key "leaders" for 300 seconds (5 minutes).

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely a more compact and concise answer; levying the check logic to a wrapper function is pretty cool too, gonna have to use this :) Only catch, is `300` the cache time? This answer says "5 minutes", so I think that's a bit long.

Comment: In 5.8 and newer the cache facade was changed to be PSR-7 compliant, it now takes a number of seconds instead of a number of minutes. So 300 seconds == 5 minutes in this case

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That makes sense!

Comment: Sorry, but my version is under 5.8 hehe. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

***Laravel*** > 7 u can use cash::rmember(), and u will save a lot with writing less
Example :

```php
$getleaders = Cache::remember('getleaders', 'minutes', function () {
 u query;
  });
```